# Mouse pointer missing in SSH windows

Tags: linux, ssh, mouse, xorg, mouse-cursor

I have a problem with the mouse pointer when I use SSH to launch a remote window.

I run `ssh -CY somehost` and then run some command that opens a new window. When the mouse pointer enters that new window it is not visible. I can move and click and if I hit my target everything else works but the pointer is not visible.

I searched for an answer nothing came out, any hints?